# How to fix ntfs-3g.usermap "You have defined no user" failure?

Tags: permissions, ntfs

Well, AskUbuntu insist this title is "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed", I really don't see what is subjective here - all I want is `ntfs-3g.usermap` to succeed.

Trying to get permissions on an NTFS USB disk drive, I found [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition), so I unmounted the drive and tried:

```
$ sudo ntfs-3g.usermap /dev/disk/by-label/MYNTFS 

This tool will help you to build a mapping of Windows users
to Linux users.
Be prepared to give Linux user id (uid) and group id (gid)
for owners of files which will be selected.
"/dev/disk/by-label/MYNTFS" opened

* Scanning "/dev/disk/by-label/MYNTFS" (two levels)
* Search for "Documents and Settings" and "Users"
* Search for other directories /
"/dev/disk/by-label/MYNTFS" closed

You have defined no user, no mapping can be built
```

Well, I do have a user ?! This drive was formatted on Mac OSX I remember, does that maybe have influence on this?

Why do I get this error - and how can I have `ntfs-3g.usermap` command to succeed?

Comment: Have you tried to mount just the disk instead of that particular location?

Comment: Thanks @Brian, but I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: As you figured out, it was searching for specific directories for windows users.  My suggestion was to mount the disk at the root of it, instead of a path, which would hopefully return a list of windows users, however, as we now know, they were never going to be found.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there has been a misunderstanding on my part: I thought `ntfs-3g.usermap` is to allow Linux users (and thus permissions) to function on an NTFS drive; what it does instead is try to map Windows users found on the drive to Linux users.

I guess this implies that one has to have Windows installed on that NTFS drive/partition - however, this is a removable drive with just "plain" files, and furthermore formatted on a Mac OSX, and as such there is no reason why it would have any Windows users defined - which explains why the command behaves as it does.